# Where to start using BDD on existing system?

Tags: bdd

We have been using waterfall to develop and enhance the system in our company and recently we are moving into Agile and the management is interested in BDD.

My understanding is that BDD is a tool for business and development team to refine the stories and at the same time these scenarios will become test cases for the feature. This sounds perfect to me but since we already have the features available, how can BDD work in this type of situation?

Should we just write up the stories and scenarios per our knowledge of the feature?
My only concern of the above is the coverage of the scenarios. Or we shouldn't worry and keep adding new scenarios and test it whenever the team came up with new ones?

Comment: are u planning TDD also?

Comment: Since you're not asking about problems with *specific* code SO isn't really the best site. Instead, you should consider asking this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ where the more abstract/whiteboard questions are on-topic...

Comment: Yes Blacksonic. We are trying to start practising this

Comment: Hi Jon, I saw some articles about BDD on this site, that's why I am asking the question here hoping some gurus can help answering my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Prompted by yet another person who mailed me with the same question today, I've [written up an answer for this](http://lizkeogh.com/2014/01/22/using-bdd-with-legacy-systems/).

Short version, you can use BDD to help you understand what the system actually does, and why, but you'll be clarifying the requirements rather than exploring them.

Additionally, you asked, "Should we just write up the stories and scenarios per our knowledge of the feature?"

I'd speak with any stakeholders you can find, ask them what the system *should* do, then look to see if it actually does it. Systems designed before adopting a practice of conversations with examples often don't do what the originators intended. You can then differentiate between the behaviour you've actually got, while creating a new backlog from the behaviour you want.

I advise grabbing someone who's good at asking questions and spotting missing scenarios to have these discussions with (usually a tester). Because you already have some knowledge of the system, it's likely you'll be very good at describing what you think it does, while missing gaps.

Comment: Thank you! It was me to wrote to you through your site. Your article is really helpful. It is very challenging for us as this is a brand new technique and team are excited about it and yet worried about it at the same time. :)

Comment: If you're completely new to BDD, you might also like my tutorial slide deck. It's all annotated; you can download it and read the notes as you play it. Quite long but pretty thorough IMO! Good luck! http://www.slideshare.net/lunivore/behavior-driven-development-11754474

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any automated testing yet and you want to start using BDD, I would suggest you to start by writing some Scenarios for some of your manual tests scripts, I find it to be a good way to train the writing of the BDD style, then as Lunivore said, you should work together with the business people and QA to find out better about the behaviour of your system and preferably write the scenarios with them.